# I have UI View Controllers embedded in Tab Bar Controller. How can I change the lower tab bar icons to textfield on one view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, uitabbar

So this is how my story board looks like:

[image]

user has a tabbar with 3 icons on the bar and he can choose the tab that he wants to see. Then, from the 1st tab, he can press the button and he sees the `TextDetails` screen. Currently this screen 'inherits' the icons from the tab bar. Is there a possibility to change it so that there's only a UITextField there (instead of 3 icons)?